JS promises will run parallelly or one by one
Need to now about the promises , The JS promises will run parallelly or not
this is the below code I'm using, Here I am creating three promises and checking the execution time


const startTime=Date.now()

const record1= new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  for(i=0;i<100;i++){
      for(j=0;j<100;j++){
          console.log(`${i}${j}`)
      }
  }
  resolve(Date.now()-startTime)
})

const record2= new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  for(k=0;k<100;k++){
      for(l=0;l<100;l++){
          console.log(`${k}${l}`)
      }
  }
  resolve(Date.now()-startTime)
})

const record3= new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  for(m=0;m<100;m++){
      for(n=0;n<100;n++){
          console.log(`${m}${n}`)
      }
  }
  resolve(Date.now()-startTime)
})
Promise.all([
  record1,
  record2,
  record3
]).then((msg)=>{
  console.log(msg)
})



This is the output I'm getting:
[ 1089, 2755, 3943 ]

"JS promises will run parallelly or not?": Promises don't run: they are objects, not functions. JS does not execute JS code in parallel, unless you involve workers.

"This is the output I'm getting:" What did you expect to happen? What exactly is the question here?

The code that you pass to the Promise constructor runs immediately, not asynchronously. Also, js runs in one tread (if not executed in a worker)

You can't use promises to execute synchronous code in parallell just as your output indicates.
As mentioned in the comments, for that purpose you need web workers.
Common use case for promise.all is multiple API calls.
Here's a simple implementation of a web worker.
You can't run the example here. And locally it must run on a server due to security issues.
If you have node you can simply run npx serve to get it running.


//worker.js
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    const callerId = event.data;  
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        for(j=0;j<100;j++){
            console.log(`Worker ${callerId} ${i}${j}`)
        }
    }
  self.postMessage(`worker ${callerId} done`);
};
<script>
const worker1 = new Worker('worker.js');
const worker2 = new Worker('worker.js');
const worker3 = new Worker('worker.js');

const t = performance.now();
worker1.onmessage = event => console.log(performance.now() - t, event.data);
worker2.onmessage = event => console.log(performance.now() - t, event.data);
worker3.onmessage = event => console.log(performance.now() - t, event.data);

worker1.postMessage(1);
worker2.postMessage(2);
worker3.postMessage(3);
</script>



Run on my system without the inner loop console log

